# Excel error 1004 "Unable to get SumIfs property of WorksheetFunction class" appearing inconsistently

Tags: vbcodeprovider

Option Explicit

Sub UpdateWeeklySummary()
Dim dailyCountSheet As Worksheet
Dim weeklySummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim processRange As Range
Dim processCell As Range
Dim weekRange As Range
Dim weekCell As Range
Dim currentWeek As Integer
Dim weeklyCount As Integer

```
Set dailyCountSheet = Worksheets("Daily Count")
Set weeklySummarySheet = Worksheets("WeeklySummary")

'Loop through each row in the process range
Set processRange = dailyCountSheet.Range("A2:A5")
For Each processCell In processRange
    'Loop through each column in the week range
    Set weekRange = dailyCountSheet.Range("B1:F1")
    For Each weekCell In weekRange
        'Calculate the week number for the current column
        currentWeek = WeekNum(weekCell.Value)
        
        'Calculate the total count for the current week and process
        weeklyCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(dailyCountSheet.Range("B2:F5"), dailyCountSheet.Range("A2:A5"), processCell.Value, dailyCountSheet.Range("B1:F1"), ">=" & weekCell.Value, dailyCountSheet.Range("B1:F1"), "<=" & DateAdd("d", 6, weekCell.Value))
        
        'Update the corresponding cell in the weekly summary table
        weeklySummarySheet.Cells(processCell.Row, currentWeek + 1).Value = weeklyCount
    Next weekCell
Next processCell

MsgBox "Weekly summary updated successfully."
```

End Sub

Function WeekNum(dt As Date) As Integer
WeekNum = DatePart("ww", dt, vbMonday)
End Function

I need to pull the data from daily count sheet and calculate each week wise in weekly summary sheet.